# How do I equally space out css grid columns?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid that displays data in a tabular format. The previous developer at my company used the grid-template-columns and minmax properties to implement the view but one of the tables has a a wide first column and every other column is alright. How do I equally space them out so they're the same width?

I've tried using minmax(auto, 1fr) and repeat(auto-fill, minmax(max-content, 1fr)) but it just messes up the entire structure of the view

The main container has the following CSS:

```
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, 30%) 1fr auto;
    justify-content: center;
```

And the prt of the page that displays the table data is this :

```
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 1fr);
```

I expect the spacing to be equal across every column

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKrLJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your HTML and include a minimal example: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of 3 equal columns using grid:

```css
.parent {
  background: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.child-1 {
  background: red;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3 end;
}

.child-2 {
  background: green;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3 end;
}

.child-3 {
  background: black;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3 end;
}

@-- Non-Grid Styles --@

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.child-1,
.child-2,
.child-3 {
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">child 1</div>
  <div class="child-2">child 2</div>
  <div class="child-3">child 3</div>
</div>
```

This link has excellent explanations of how to use grid: [Grid Info](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)